# Using FixInNameSpace Creates Error

Tags: r, quantmod

I'm following the instructions in this post

[Y Axis is cut off using Chartseries in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23032224/y-axis-is-cut-off-using-chartseries-in-r][1])

to change the `chartSeries` function in quantmod.

But when I touch the file at all using `FixInNameSpace`:

```
fixInNamespace(x = "chartSeries.chob", pos = as.environment("package:quantmod"))
```

(even if I don't edit it at all)

.. I then get

> Error in chartSeries.chob() :    could not
>   find function "chart.layout"

when I call `chartSeries`.

Comment: Sorry for being a nudge.  I tried to do it.  Thanks for the advice FXQuant

Comment: What you're describing works fine for me.  Can you be a bit more specific about how to reproduce your problem?  `library(quantmod); getSymbols("AAPL"); fixInNamespace(x = "chartSeries.chob", pos = as.environment("package:quantmod"));` .. then add a print statement, then call `chartSeries(AAPL)` works fine for me (testing from within Rstudio)

Comment: Have you tried doing simply these changes from a fresh restart of R and a clean workspace?

Comment: clean start of RStudio, then:rm(list = ls())
library(quantmod); 
getSymbols("AAPL"); 
fixInNamespace(x = "chartSeries.chob", pos = as.environment("package:quantmod"))
chartSeries(AAPL)

…after cancelling the edit produces….

> rm(list = ls())
> library(quantmod); 
> getSymbols("AAPL"); 
[1] "AAPL"
> fixInNamespace(x = "chartSeries.chob", pos = as.environment("package:quantmod"))
> chartSeries(AAPL)
Error in chartSeries.chob(<S4 object of class "chob">) : 
  could not find function "chart.layout"

Comment: Same problem here. Any solutions?