# changing the side of bottom facet of graph in chart_Series quantmod

Tags: r, plot, xts, quantmod

I would like to know if i can increase the size of the bottom pane of the graph on the plot function chart_Series()

```
chart_Series(x$A, TA="add_TA(x$B)")
```

you don't need data to know what this will look like...[image: this shows the output of the chart_Series function with TA]

Comment: I'm new to this...  I was unaware I needed to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to modify some aspects of `chart_Series` using the `pars` and `theme` objects you can optionally pass to `chart_Series`.  But I don't know if there is a way to feed in modifying the size of the y axis in `add_TA` etc without directly modifying the source code for `add_TA`.  This is what I've done before, which is a bit messy, but works ... modify the source code.

The line in `add_TA` you want to modify is this, which is hard coded as (approximatly line 61 of `add_TA`):

```
plot_object$add_frame(ylim = range(na.omit(xdata)), 
            asp = 1)
```

Changing that line to this (the value of `asp` (aspect?) is changed), will give you something like what you want:

```
plot_object$add_frame(ylim = range(na.omit(xdata)), 
                      asp = 3)
```

This change gives:

```
getSymbols("AAPL")
chart_Series(AAPL["2016"])
my_add_TA(SMA(AAPL["2016", 4]))  #my_add_TA is add_TA with asp line changed
```

[image]
If you're unsure about how to modify the source code of a package, you could follow my answer to a related question here [modify chart_Series source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20337851/r-quantmod-chart-series-using-large-fonts-for-y-axis/23637020#23637020) on modifying `chart_Series` as one approach.  Another approach is just to recompile the source code for the package with your modifications.

Comment: Why not make it an argument passable to the add_TA() function... such that the asp value can be passed...

Comment: Yep you can, if you carefully pass the argument into the environments used in add_TA.  I don't think the author of this package is updating this package at the moment though (not for several years), so `chart_Series` and related are likely to stay in 'alpha' for some time.  Just make your own edits to the source :D